# <slot> element before pseudo text not showing up in iOS devices

Tags: html, css

Trying to find the solution for a few hours, but no luck. Please help me if you can or suggest me a different solution.

Here is my code which is working every desktop/tablet/android except iOS devices (iPhone/iPad):

```css
slot[name=modal-title]:before {
  content: "Offer Disclaimer";
  display: block;
  color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<slot name="modal-title"></slot>
```

I don't have control over the HTML, so only options are CSS/js

Comment: Do you just want to add the text within your `slot` tag?

Comment: @SMAKSS: correct, I won't be able to edit the HTML since it's coming from external API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, **`content` property is supported in safari browsers, but it may not work properly on all devices and versions**. So instead try to add the text with the JS.

Your final code should be something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('slot[name=modal-title]').innerHTML = 'Offer Disclaimer'
```

```css
slot[name=modal-title] {
  display: block;
  color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<slot name="modal-title"></slot>
```